# i am having error running the command, bundle exec gaurd init

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**I am following mhartl's 3rd editon tutorials.**`https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages`

My development enviornment is **https://ide.c9.io**

**So when i try to run the command**`bundle exec gaurd init`

I get the error  **`bundler: command not found: gaurd
Install missing gem executables with bundle install`**

Here is the **[Gemfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZQO3.jpg)**

**Gemfile.lock**

```html
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (2.3.2)
    actionmailer (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.3.pre1)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.4.0)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.49.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    faker (1.4.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    fission (0.5.0)
      CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
    fog (1.36.0)
      fog-aliyun (>= 0.1.0)
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (>= 0.6.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-core (~> 1.32)
      fog-dynect (~> 0.0.2)
      fog-ecloud (~> 0.1)
      fog-google (<= 0.1.0)
      fog-json
      fog-local
      fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-riakcs
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-xenserver
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    fog-aliyun (0.1.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
      xml-simple (~> 1.1)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (0.9.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.10.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-core (1.39.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.49)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
    fog-dynect (0.0.3)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-google (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-json (1.0.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-local (0.3.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
    fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-profitbricks (0.0.5)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
      nokogiri
    fog-radosgw (0.0.5)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-sakuracloud (1.7.5)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (1.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xenserver (0.2.3)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-minitest (2.3.1)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jbuilder (2.2.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.10)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.0)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
    mini_backtrace (0.1.3)
      minitest (> 1.2.0)
      rails (>= 2.3.3)
    mini_magick (3.8.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    notiffany (0.1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    puma (3.1.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activerecord (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.2)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.1.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    ruby_dep (1.3.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (3.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    subexec (0.2.3)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (= 0.7.3.pre1)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.7)
    xml-simple (1.1.5)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt (= 3.1.7)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.2.0.0)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  byebug (= 3.4.0)
  carrierwave (= 0.10.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.1.0)
  faker (= 1.4.2)
  fog (= 1.36.0)
  guard-minitest (= 2.3.1)
  jbuilder (= 2.2.3)
  jquery-rails (= 4.0.3)
  mini_backtrace (= 0.1.3)
  mini_magick (= 3.8.0)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.0.5)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  puma (= 3.1.0)
  rails (= 4.2.2)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.2)
  sdoc (= 0.4.0)
  spring (= 1.1.3)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.9)
  turbolinks (= 2.3.0)
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)
  web-console (= 2.0.0.beta3)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.7)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.3
```

I have tried running codes: **gem update bundler**
But still having same error.
I am not sure whats happening here , why the gaurd command is not running.

**I am seeking for help!**
**Please help me out to get rid of this error.**

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Comment: I have added the  above code to both the files that is .bash_rc and .bash_profile. But still i am having same type of error.  'bundler: command not found: gaurd  
Install missing gem executables with bundle install'

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelt `guard` as `gaurd`.